# Angular application with different Application paths?

Tags: angularjs

I have two applications deployed on the same server.Both are angular based applications.

One with a URL like :
http://localhost:8080/something/debug.html

the other as :

http://localhost:8080/somethingElse/debug.html

I want to combine these applications so that I can have the same header which can then router to individual contents within a container.
What is the best way of achieving this in angular JS?

Comment: Do you mean you want to combine them as a single application? or do you want to keep them deployed in different URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep them deployed in different URLs, I believe there's no "Angular way" of doing it and you'd have to use `iframe`. Keep in mind that the application inside the `iframe` would have no communication with the elements outside of it.

If you want to merge both apps as a single one, keep in mind that AngularJS only allows the use of one `ng-app` directive per application, and if you, so you will have to do some small refactoring:

1. Create a new AngularJS module that has the other 2 existing ones as dependencies.
2. Create your `index.html` with the global layout and use the `ng-app` directive to reference the newly created module.
3. Use a tool such as **ui-router** or **ngRoute** to set up the routes to the existing applications,making sure the states/urls don't collide.

> If each application uses a different routing library, you'll have to refactor them to use the same one, or else there will be conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router to create a main route, which links to the two individual app routes.